# Can I replace a 1.25w LED stair light fixture with a 2w LED light fixture on a string of 7 light fixtures?

Tags: electrical, led, light

What can I replace a discontinued 1.25w 350mA LED stair light fixture with (7 light run, 1.25w ea)? Can I replace it with a lower 1w fixture or can I replace it with a higher 2w fixture?  Is the mA of the fixture a concern?

Comment: Simply asking the question again doesn't make it any different...

Comment: The forum asked me to rephrase my question. Not sure why.

Comment: Your other question was closed as off-topic as a shopping question. I'd suggest that you edit the other question to be more specific about what info you need. What info, exactly, are you looking to confirm? I'm sure you're not looking for someone to recommend a brand/model, but we're not sure what info you _do_ need. Let us know what it is that has you confused, and I'm sure the other one will be reopened and we'll be able to get you the info you're after.